# How do I filter/modify the updated content on save using javascript?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I want to use js to filter content being saved in the Gutenberg editor for pages. So far I have this, which will get the content on save, but let's say I want to append `xxxxxx` to the end of the content when it's saved (and also update the wysiwyg editor). Also want it to run every time the user hits the update button. how would I do this?

```
const unsubscribe = wp.data.subscribe(function () {
    const editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');

    if (
        true === editor.isSavingPost() &&
        false === editor.isAutosavingPost() &&
        true === editor.didPostSaveRequestSucceed() &&
        'page' === editor.getCurrentPost().type
    ) {

        unsubscribe();

        wp.data
            .dispatch('core/notices')
            .createNotice('success', 'post edited', {
                type: 'snackbar',
                isDismissible: true,
            });

        //What to do here?
    }
});
```

Also, where can I learn how to do this sort of thing? I can't find much documentation but I know this is done by many people.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by adding:

```js
// What to do here?
wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').insertDefaultBlock({content:'xxxxxx'});
```

This will insert a block with the specified text to the end of the blocks list when the user will hit the update button. Once, and then it will self-unsubscribe.

To run it every time the user hits the update button, you don't want to `unsubscribe()`. This example will add `xxxxxx` every time:

```js
const editor = wp.data.select("core/editor");
let wasSavingPost = editor.isSavingPost();
let wasAutosavingPost = editor.isAutosavingPost();

const unsubscribe = wp.data.subscribe(() => {
  const isSavingPost = editor.isSavingPost();
  const isAutosavingPost = editor.isAutosavingPost();

  const shouldTriggerAddXXXXXX =
    wasSavingPost &&
    !wasAutosavingPost &&
    !isSavingPost &&
    "page" === editor.getCurrentPost().type;

  wasSavingPost = isSavingPost;
  wasAutosavingPost = isAutosavingPost;

  if (shouldTriggerAddXXXXXX) {
    wp.data
      .dispatch("core/block-editor")
      .insertDefaultBlock({ content: "xxxxxx" });
  }
});
```

Note that it will not update the post in the database after last insertion of `xxxxxx`, because code is executed after saving.

You can learn more about this sort of thing in the [Reference Guides of the Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/).